# How can I solve this error in python after create exe file with pyinstaller? "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'"

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal, pyinstaller

I have used tkinter in Python and created an exe file with pyinstaller with this :

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py`

My code ran without a single problem but after creating an exe file and running it I got this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

I checked all questions like this and used all the solutions and none of them worked like I used hidden import in many ways.
I have this problem with another library named 'jdatetime'.
I also asked chat GPT and her solution not working.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue when I compile a test script using `PyInstaller` version 6.3.0.

Comment: @acw1668 Do you think maybe it interferes with something else?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had installed these packages only on the virtual machine.

With other packages, I have no problem. But I have a problem with these two.